# undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when trying to access items in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, ruby, indexing, rubygems

I can't access items from this array and I'm not sure why.

I'm using a Gem called FastImage that takes image URLs and return its properties to crawl a webpage and return the width and height of all the images it finds.

```
- url = open("http://google.com/").read

- imgs = URI.extract(url).select{|img| img[/\.(?:png|jpe?g)\b/]}.each do |img|  
  = FastImage.size(img)
```

This prints the dimensions in each respective array but trying to access an item by its index with `[]` returns the above error.

Comment: If this prints the dimensions, then it obviously doesn't raise an error here (although there are holes in your code that will make it not print dimensions, as not all of the selected things are actually image names). Please show which part of the code is throwing an error.

Comment: It doesn't exclusively grab the image tags, that's not what I'm worried about. Appending an index on the end of the array like this: [0] causes the error.

Comment: Appending it like *how*? It's not clear from your explanation.

Comment: `[0]` by itself is not an index, it is a one-element list. Please show the complete code that generates the error. What are you appending `[0]` to?

Comment: FastImage.size(img)[0] or (FastImage.size(img))[0], doesn't make a difference

Comment: If you are trying to access `FastImage.size(img)[0]`, then of course you'll get the error. "It doesn't exclusively grab the image tags, that's not what I'm worried about." - well you should be: for every non-image, `FastImage.size` returns `nil`, and `nil[0]` is an error.

Comment: Alright, that's probably it then. I was confused because the array itself wasn't causing a problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `img` is not a valid URL of an image, `FastImage.size(img)` returns `nil`; `FastImage.size(img)[0]` will throw an error.

If you're on Ruby 2.3, you can write `FastImage.size(img)&.[](0)`, but it's ugly. For any Ruby, you can do this:

```
= size = FastImage.size(img) and size[0]
```

In either case, a better regular expression should cut down on false positives, which should cut down on unnecessary HTTP requests. One easy thing might be to replace `\b` with `$`, as the extension should really be the last thing in the URL (unless you have weird cache-busting URLs like `foo.jpeg?q=276747622`).